# Update my node js version with homebrew

Tags: node.js, macos, console, homebrew

I want to update my node.js version with brew on mac but I have this error:

```
Error: This command updates brew itself, and does not take formula names.
Use 'brew upgrade <formula>'.
```

Comment: is the following: `brew update`, then `brew upgrade node`, then `npm install -g npm` working?

Answer (score 8):

This error message is telling you that the command `brew update` is used to update brew itself, and that if you want to update node, you need to run `brew upgrade node`. Note the difference: 'update' vs. 'upgrade'.

You may also want to consider using [Node Version Manager (NVM)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which makes installing new node versions very simple, and allows switching back and forth between them with a single command.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough to upgrade Node in Mac using `brew`:

```
brew upgrade node
```

The above command will automatically update Homebrew as well.

```
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
```